# Angular Url with anchor tag (divid) refresh goes to home page

Tags: angular, url, refresh, anchor

I am implement the accessibility compliance in angular application and Its working fine but one little problem I am facing like in url "***http://localhost:4200/#/getdata/bulkdata#main-content***" I have added the anchor tag with div id(my main content of page), till now its working fine but any Ctrl+R or refresh url its going to home page.

I am using angular and typescript.

Any help is highly appreciated.

see the code below for html file

```
<a href="#main-content" class="skip">Skip to main content</a>
```

Below code for .ts file

```
    ngOnInit() {

  $(".skip").click(function(event){    

     $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 150
      });

    this.href = " ";
    $('#skipfooter').removeAttr('tabindex');

    if(window.location.href.indexOf('login') >=0){
      this.href=window.location.href + "#main-Content-login";   
    }

    else if (window.location.href.indexOf('#main-content') == -1){
        (this.href=window.location.href + "#main-content");
      } 
    else {this.href=window.location.href;      
    }

    var skipTo="#"+this.href.split('#')[2];       
        // Setting 'tabindex' to -1 takes an element out of normal,tab flow but allows it to be focused via javascript
    $(skipTo).attr('tabindex', -1).on('blur focusout', function () {    
         // when focus leaves this element, remove the tabindex attribute
    $(this).removeAttr('tabindex');    
   }).focus(); // focus on the content container
        });       
      }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please edit your original question and use code blocks to display your code, you should not do this in the comments. you can paste your code, select it then hit CTRL+K on the keyboard to format it. I will try to help once you have done this. Thanks

Comment: I have added the code in question block.

Comment: it sounds like you are facing a redirect issue with angular routing that doesnt understand the route. When you remove your code, does the refresh issue still happen/

Comment: Also are you using angular routing?

Comment: Hi Judson, I am using angular routing, In the url I am adding the div id as anchor tag like "http://localhost:4200/#/getdata/bulkdata#main-content", main-content is the div id. If I do not add the div id everything are working fine but when I add the div id and refresh it goes to home screen.